# Scrpay ImportError: cannot import name Request

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I have seen similar questions over this forum but this is different from those

I have Item class like this
...

```
class NewCarItem(Item):
    car_petrol_engine_type = Item()
    car_petrol_engine_size = Item()
    car_petrol_engine_max_power = Item()
    car_petrol_engine_max_torque = Item()
    car_petrol_engine_fuel_supply_system = Item()

    car_diesel_engine_type = Item()
    car_diesel_engine_size = Item()
    car_diesel_engine_max_power = Item()
    car_diesel_engine_max_torque = Item()
    car_diesel_engine_fuel_supply_system = Item()

    car_transmission_type = Item()

    car_suspension_front = Item()
    car_suspension_rear = Item()

    car_dimension_overall_length_width_height = Item()
    car_dimension_wheel = Item()
    car_dimension_fuel_tank_capacity = Item()
    car_dimension_turning_circle_radius = Item()
    car_dimension_boot_space = Item()
    car_dimension_tyre = Item()

    car_tyre_is_tube_less = Item()
```

And my spider class like this

```
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from car_planet.items import NewCarItem
from car_planet.lib.html_utils import *

class NewCarSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'new_car_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['toyotabharat.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.toyotabharat.com/cars/new_cars/']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        urls = hxs.select("//div[@id='sr-img']/a/@href").extract()
        items = []
        for url in urls:
            formed_url = "http://www.toyotabharat.com"+get_matched_strings("^(.*[\\/])",url)[0]+"spec_org.aspx"
            yield  Request(formed_url,callback=self.parse_level_one)

    def parse_level_one(self,response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        meta_tags = hxs.select("//meta").extract()
        item = NewCarItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        return item
```

And when I try to run the spider by
 scrapy crawl new_car_spider 
this command I get error something like this

```
from scrapy import Request
ImportError: cannot import name Request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You import Request from a wrong place. It is located in scrapy.http. 
Change your import like this:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some kind of misconfiguration. Possible reasons:

- package is not installed;
- it's not under PYTHONPATH, so python just can't find it;
- subset of previous point - you have several python versions installed, and this library isn't available for current one (e.g. you installed only for python 3, and trying to import by python 2)
- etc

what you can do in order to debug this issue - just `import sys; print sys.path` and check whether the librray you're trying to import is available under that pathes.